# .bin files used for upgrading embeded devices

Tags: c, linux, flash, kernel

I am confused a bit about .bin files. Basically in Linux we use elf, .ko type of files for upgrading the box or to copy in it . But, while upgrading a NAND flash in router or any Networking Gaint products why always .bin files is preferred. Is this is something like converged mix of all the OS related files. **Does it possible to see the contents of a bin file. How to play with it. It is something like contents of BootROM.** How is is prepared?  How do we create and test on this. How Linux support for this. Any historical reasons behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking about routers, those files are usually just snapshots of a router's flash memory, probably compressed and with some headers added. Typical things are a compressed squashfs image or simply `gzip`'ed snapshot of memory.

There is no such thing as `.bin` format, it's just a custom array of bytes and every vendor interprets it in some vendor-specific way. Basically this extension means “it's not your business what's in the file, our device/software will handle it”. You can try to identify (thnk, reverse-engineer) what's actually in those files by using `file` utility or just looking at those files through a hex editor and trying to guess what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, kirelagin. I am keen on the line "gzip'ed snapshot of memory". Anyhow the respective binaries and conf files must be copied to the NAND flash right. So, how does the snapshot of memory is converted to binary in the upgraded box.

Comment: The file is saved somewhere on the device (say, in `/tmp`), then it is `gunzip`ped and the resulting blocks of bytes are just copied to the flash (think `dd`).